# Is Superuser's <code> CSS light-blue highlight near invisible on anyone else's laptop LCD?

Tags: support, status-completed, color, css

I have a 15" laptop with a quality built-in LCD, but still, some very light colors wash out to where they're barely noticeable. For example the light blue background color used for the <code> tag (or four-space indents) on Superuser are pretty much impossible to see.

Even using the trick of tilting my screen until the color distorts somewhat, it's still very hard to see that effect. Anyone else having problems seeing the light background colors used in many places?

**Clarification:** I don't consider it a duplicate because the grey backgrounds for <code> blocks in all StackExchange sites but Superuser are fine with me, and the most of the non-code blue backgrounds on Superuser are fine. It's just Superuser's <code> block background color that is a super light blue, almost not worth calling blue: #F5FDFF.

It's bad enough that I feel like I can't use <code> in-line in my text on Superuser because readers won't be able to tell the difference between the command-line arguments I'm referring to, and the text around it. So I'll have to make my posts uglier and less readable by formatting them so "code" (on Superuser, at least for me, this usually means "mentions of command-line tools") are separated out to their own lines. That's too bad, because there are times when just mentioning a command or two is easier to do and more readable inline with the text.

Comment: It's weird. I'm running a 2-monitor setup and I can see them fine on one, and not at all on the other. <shrug>

Comment: Dude, it's near invisible on my CRT.

Comment: It's subtle but clearly visible to me (2 TFTs), can you test if you see #EBF3F5 (same hue, darker)? http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/htmlcolor.pl?c=F5FDFF versus http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/htmlcolor.pl?c=EBF3F5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have updated the blockquote/code background colors to gray, like the one on Stack Overflow. The change is now live.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a sample for visual reference

[image: code and blockquote colors on superuser]

I agree it's subtle, but we haven't received overwhelming complaints about this...

edit: we decided it makes sense to change this.

Comment: There *is* a feature req to change it. http://meta.superuser.com/q/3519/48078 — and it's at 12/0, which is quite a lot for MSU.

Comment: Wow. I just saw the color difference the first time ever, when I looked at my laptop TFT from an about 50 degree angle *below*. No chance at all on my tablet computer. This really should be changed.

Comment: I actually can see both fine. To see it better, I do have to tilt the screen just slightly back on my laptop, but I can make out the difference in normal viewing. Of course, YMMV. I never thought it was something really worth changing though...

Comment: Cool. Thanks Jeff! Looking forward to it...

Comment: I have been using Firefox + Stylish to override the CSS. I agree that the contrast is too low.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some technical details about the colors:

- **Body** background-color: `#FFFFFF`, rgb: `255, 255, 255`
- **Code/Blockquote** background-color: `#F5FDFF`, rgb: `245, 253, 255`

*It's nearly white!* Color-wise, I would classify it under gray not blue. I suggest increasing the **saturation** (hsv) by at least 8 units to `#E0F9FF`, rgb: `224, 249, 255`.

For comparison, the color here on Meta.SU is `#EEEEEE`, rgb: `238, 238, 238`.

---

Original:

[image: original]

+8 saturation:

[image: suggestion]

-8 value: *gray!*

[image: gray]

Comment: Saturation 8 isn't enough.