# Make "code / command"-background more visible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, color, syntax-highlighting

I write code or commands using ["backticks"](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help#code). But on SuperUser, the background doesn't have much visual contrast, so if I write multiple commands separated with comma or a single word, it's hard to distinguish between the commands and the words between. If the "code/command" background color was more visible this had been more readable.

e.g. when listing commands like: `command 1`, `command 2` and `command 3`.

For an example, see [How can I print an environment variable from the command prompt in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/341192/how-can-i-print-an-environment-variable-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7)

Comment: I agree. The contrast is very low. I have worked around this by using the Stylish extension for Firefox.

Comment: Thank you @Jin!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean this …

[image]

… becomes this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would be more readable.

Comment: Yes, the visual contrast is a bit low. It works way better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: More! Some of us are too cheap for good IPS panels.