# Use block quote style from SU on MSU

Tags: feature-request, css, meta

Block quotes are a good (if semantically questionable) way to visually separate e.g. screenshots as part of a post on SU, which might otherwise be mistaken as part of the post text, since the get a line on the left side (similar to some email clients' quoting).

[image]

On MSU, where we regularly include e.g. screenshots of the regular site into posts, it's different:

> like this

Unfortunately, it's not nearly as useful when including *partial screenshots of a web page*, this the background color becomes a not nearly as visible border around the image. Compare the following screenshots taken from a slightly modified version of [this post by slhck](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3520/22317).

---

### Block quote MSU

[image]

---

### Block quote SU

[image]

---

### Request

The border on the left side works much better to separate the images from the text of the post.

Please chance the MSU `blockquote` style to the one used on SU (maybe with less/no saturation in the border color, but a similar overall style).

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... just that SU [now inherits](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1026/4377) somewhat of a MSU styling.

Comment: Except that SU still has the border, while msu doesn't.