# <!--Oops--> Less-than and greater-than characters are not being handled properly in Stack Exchange inbox email notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, globalinbox

Less-than and greater-than characters are not being handled properly in Stack Exchange inbox email notifications.

This is troublesome when a post title contains HTML tags, as they will be sent as HTML in the email notifications. For example, the question [Is Superuser's <code> CSS light-blue highlight near invisible on anyone else's laptop LCD?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1026/100787) has `<code>` in the title.

The less-than and greater-than characters should be converted to the proper HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Instead, they are sent as raw code.

> [image: example]

**Note:** The characters display properly on the StackExchange sites.

> [image: example2]

### Just as I thought!...

> [image: example3]

Comment: Nothing to discuss about it. It's *broken*.

Comment: @DanielBeck Fixed!

Comment: -1 Power users use RSS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next build will fix* this, we weren't encoding items titles properly for the email (and only the email it looks like).

<sub>*Should be within the hour.</sub>